# N-Body CUDA optimization

Tags: cuda, simulation

I'm developing an N-body algorithm in CUDA and I would like to learn some tips and tricks for optimization.

I've managed to get `16384` bodies to run at `20Flops` on an NVIDIA Geforce GTX 260, which has `27` Streaming Multiprocessors.

The `KernelcomputeForces` function is the slow poke taking about `95%` of the time and I was wondering if there is anymore that I can do to optimize my code.

As far as I see, I've optimized for memory-space-locality and memory-writing. Somewhere in the CUDA docs, it says shared-memory is faster but I dont see how I can make use of that. I've divided the work in `16` blocks with `512` threads on each, but thats a bit fuzzy for me.

Please help and thanks for reading this.

```
n   is number of bodies

gm  is the gpu mass pointer

gpx is the gpu position x pointer

gpy is the gpu position y pointer

gpz is the gpu position z pointer

gfx is the gpu force x pointer

gfy is the gpu force y pointer

gfz is the gpu force z pointer
```

**The relevant kernel function**

```
__global__ void KernelcomputeForces( unsigned int n, float* gm, float* gpx, float* gpy, float* gpz, float* gfx, float* gfy, float* gfz ){
    int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int numThreads = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

    float GRAVITY = 0.00001f;

    //compare all with all
    for( unsigned int ia=tid; ia<n; ia+=numThreads ){
        float lfx = 0.0f;
        float lfy = 0.0f;
        float lfz = 0.0f;

        for( unsigned int ib=0; ib<n; ib++ ){
            //compute distance
            float dx = ( gpx[ib] - gpx[ia]);
            float dy = ( gpy[ib] - gpy[ia] );
            float dz = ( gpz[ib] - gpz[ia] );
            //float distance = sqrt( dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz );
            float distanceSquared = dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz;

            //prevent slingshots and division by zero
            //distance += 0.1f;
            distanceSquared += 0.01f;

            //calculate gravitational magnitude between the bodies
            //float magnitude = GRAVITY * ( gm[ia] * gm[ib] ) / ( distance * distance * distance * distance );
            float magnitude = GRAVITY * ( gm[ia] * gm[ib] ) / ( distanceSquared );

            //calculate forces for the bodies
            //magnitude times direction
            lfx += magnitude * ( dx );
            lfy += magnitude * ( dy );
            lfz += magnitude * ( dz );
        }

        //stores local memory to global memory
        gfx[ia] = lfx;
        gfy[ia] = lfy;
        gfz[ia] = lfz;
    }
}

extern void GPUcomputeForces( unsigned int n, float* gm, float* gpx, float* gpy, float* gpz, float* gfx, float* gfy, float* gfz ){  
    dim3 gridDim( 16, 1, 1 ); //specifys how many blocks in three possible dimensions
    dim3 blockDim( 512, 1, 1 ); //threads per block
    KernelcomputeForces<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>( n, gm, gpx, gpy, gpz, gfx, gfy, gfz );
}
```

Comment: I agree, I don't see an immediate way to use shared memory in this code as each thread accesses all of the global memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shared memory is going to be a useful optimization in this sort of kernel - it allows coalescing of the reads of particle positions and masses, which on a GT200 will be very important. I found this to be about twice as fast as your version (launched with your 16384 particles using a 128 blocks of 128 threads):

```
template<int blocksize>
__global__
void KernelcomputeForces1( unsigned int n1, float* gm, float* gpx,
                float* gpy, float* gpz, float* gfx, float* gfy, float* gfz )
{
    __shared__ float lgpx[blocksize], lgpy[blocksize],
               lgpz[blocksize], lgm[blocksize];

    const float GRAVITY = 0.00001f;

    //compare all with all
    float lfx = 0.0f, lfy = 0.0f, lfz = 0.0f;
    int ia = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    float lgpx0 = gpx[ia], lgpy0 = gpy[ia],
          lgpz0 = gpz[ia], lgm0 = gm[ia];

    for( unsigned int ib=0; ib<n1; ib+=blocksize ){

        lgpx[threadIdx.x] = gpx[ib + threadIdx.x];
        lgpy[threadIdx.x] = gpy[ib + threadIdx.x];
        lgpz[threadIdx.x] = gpz[ib + threadIdx.x];
        lgm[threadIdx.x] = gm[ib + threadIdx.x];
        __syncthreads();

#pragma unroll
        for(unsigned int ic=0; ic<blocksize; ic++) {

            //compute distance
            float dx = ( lgpx[ic] - lgpx0 );
            float dy = ( lgpy[ic] - lgpy0 );
            float dz = ( lgpz[ic] - lgpz0 );
            float distanceSquared = dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz;

            //prevent slingshots and division by zero
            distanceSquared += 0.01f;

            //calculate gravitational magnitude between the bodies
            float magnitude = GRAVITY * ( lgm0 * lgm[ic] )
                    / ( distanceSquared );

            //calculate forces for the bodies
            //magnitude times direction
            lfx += magnitude * ( dx );
            lfy += magnitude * ( dy );
            lfz += magnitude * ( dz );
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    //stores local memory to global memory
    gfx[ia] = lfx;
    gfy[ia] = lfy;
    gfz[ia] = lfz;
}
```

You would need to do something a little different for the number of particles which fall outside the nice multiple of block size, probably a second stanza which won't be unrolled. Watch the potential for warp divergence with the __syncthreads() calls, that can make the kernel hang if you are not careful.

Comment: i wonder though if i have 27 Multiprocessors wouldn't it be optimum to use 27 threads?

Comment: No. Every multiprocessor on a gt200 class gpu needs at least 192 threads just to cover the instruction pipeline latency. You want the number of blocks to be a round multiple of 27 - any block only ever run on a single multiprocessor, with each block having an round multiple of 32 threads, which is the basic scheduling granularity of the GPU.

Comment: okay thank all ive got all i wanted to know now. next up, water particle simulation :D

Answer (score 6):

@talonmies has already answered this question, showing how shared memory is helpful to improve performance. So, there is not much more to add. I just want to provide a full code, with different optimization steps, including **tiling**, **shared memory**, and **shuffle operations**, and show some results of a testing performed on a Kepler K20c.

The code below, moulded around what presented by @talonmies, has `5` kernel functions, namely

*`KernelcomputeForces`*: no optimization

*`KernelcomputeForces_Shared`*: exploits tiling in the source masses and shared memory

*`KernelcomputeForces_Tiling`*: exploits tiling in the destination masses

*`KernelcomputeForces_Tiling_Shared`*: exploits both tiling in the source and destination masses and exploits shared memory

*`KernelcomputeForces_Tiling_Shuffle`*: same as above, but uses shuffle operations instead of shared memory.

Perhaps, as compared to what already published in the literature ([Fast N-Body Simulation with CUDA](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch31.html)) and what already available as codes (see the above answers and [Mark Harris' GitHub N-body page](https://github.com/harrism/mini-nbody/tree/master/cuda), the last kernel is the only new thing. But I have played a bit with N-body, and found it useful to post this answer, potentially useful to next users.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define GRAVITATIONAL_CONST 6.67*1e−11
#define SOFTENING 1e-9f

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

/**********/
/* iDivUp */
/**********/
int iDivUp(int a, int b) { return ((a % b) != 0) ? (a / b + 1) : (a / b); }

/*******************/
/* KERNEL FUNCTION */
/*******************/
template<int BLOCKSIZE>
__global__
void KernelcomputeForces(float* m_d, float* x_d, float* y_d, float* z_d, float* fx_d, float* fy_d, float* fz_d, unsigned int N)
{
    int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (tid < N) {

        float invDist, invDist3;

        // --- Initialize register accumulators for forces
        float fx_temp = 0.0f, fy_temp = 0.0f, fz_temp = 0.0f;

        // --- Move target particle data to registers
        float x_reg = x_d[tid], y_reg = y_d[tid], z_reg = z_d[tid], m_reg = m_d[tid];

        // --- Interact all with all    
        for(unsigned int ib=0; ib<N; ib++) {

            // --- Compute relative distances
            float dx = (x_d[ib] - x_reg);
            float dy = (y_d[ib] - y_reg);
            float dz = (z_d[ib] - z_reg);
            float distanceSquared = dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz;

            // --- Prevent slingshots and division by zero
            distanceSquared += SOFTENING;

            float invDist = rsqrtf(distanceSquared);
            float invDist3 = invDist * invDist * invDist;

            // --- Calculate gravitational magnitude between the bodies
            float magnitude = GRAVITATIONAL_CONST * (m_reg * m_d[ib]) * invDist3;

            // --- Calculate forces for the bodies: magnitude times direction
            fx_temp += magnitude*dx;
            fy_temp += magnitude*dy;
            fz_temp += magnitude*dz;
        }

        // --- Stores local memory to global memory
        fx_d[tid] = fx_temp;
        fy_d[tid] = fy_temp;
        fz_d[tid] = fz_temp;
    }
}

/**********************************/
/* KERNEL FUNCTION: SHARED MEMORY */
/**********************************/
template<int BLOCKSIZE>
__global__
void KernelcomputeForces_Shared(float* m_d, float* x_d, float* y_d, float* z_d, float* fx_d, float* fy_d, float* fz_d, unsigned int N)
{
    int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (tid < N) {

        float invDist, invDist3;

        __shared__ float x_sh[BLOCKSIZE], y_sh[BLOCKSIZE], z_sh[BLOCKSIZE], m_sh[BLOCKSIZE];

        // --- Initialize register accumulators for forces
        float fx_temp = 0.0f, fy_temp = 0.0f, fz_temp = 0.0f;

        // --- Move target particle data to registers
        float x_reg = x_d[tid], y_reg = y_d[tid], z_reg = z_d[tid], m_reg = m_d[tid];

        // --- Interact all with all    
        for(unsigned int ib=0; ib<N; ib+=BLOCKSIZE) {

            // --- Loading data to shared memory
            x_sh[threadIdx.x] = x_d[ib + threadIdx.x];
            y_sh[threadIdx.x] = y_d[ib + threadIdx.x];
            z_sh[threadIdx.x] = z_d[ib + threadIdx.x];
            m_sh[threadIdx.x] = m_d[ib + threadIdx.x];

            __syncthreads();

#pragma unroll
            for(unsigned int ic=0; ic<BLOCKSIZE; ic++) {

                // --- Compute relative distances
                float dx = (x_sh[ic] - x_reg);
                float dy = (y_sh[ic] - y_reg);
                float dz = (z_sh[ic] - z_reg);
                float distanceSquared = dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz;

                // --- Prevent slingshots and division by zero
                distanceSquared += SOFTENING;

                float invDist = rsqrtf(distanceSquared);
                float invDist3 = invDist * invDist * invDist;

                // --- Calculate gravitational magnitude between the bodies
                float magnitude = GRAVITATIONAL_CONST * (m_reg * m_sh[ic]) * invDist3;

                // --- Calculate forces for the bodies: magnitude times direction
                fx_temp += magnitude*dx;
                fy_temp += magnitude*dy;
                fz_temp += magnitude*dz;
            }
            __syncthreads();
        }

        // --- Stores local memory to global memory
        fx_d[tid] = fx_temp;
        fy_d[tid] = fy_temp;
        fz_d[tid] = fz_temp;
    }
}

/***************************/
/* KERNEL FUNCTION: TILING */
/***************************/
template<int BLOCKSIZE>
__global__
void KernelcomputeForces_Tiling(float* m_d, float* x_d, float* y_d, float* z_d, float* fx_d, float* fy_d, float* fz_d, unsigned int N)
{
    float invDist, invDist3;

    for (unsigned int tid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
                  tid < N;
                  tid += blockDim.x*gridDim.x) {

        // --- Initialize register accumulators for forces
        float fx_temp = 0.0f, fy_temp = 0.0f, fz_temp = 0.0f;

        // --- Move target particle data to registers
        float x_reg = x_d[tid], y_reg = y_d[tid], z_reg = z_d[tid], m_reg = m_d[tid];

        // --- Interact all with all    
        for(unsigned int ib=0; ib<N; ib++) {

            // --- Compute relative distances
            float dx = (x_d[ib] - x_reg);
            float dy = (y_d[ib] - y_reg);
            float dz = (z_d[ib] - z_reg);
            float distanceSquared = dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz;

            // --- Prevent slingshots and division by zero
            distanceSquared += SOFTENING;

            float invDist = rsqrtf(distanceSquared);
            float invDist3 = invDist * invDist * invDist;

            // --- Calculate gravitational magnitude between the bodies
            float magnitude = GRAVITATIONAL_CONST * (m_reg * m_d[ib]) * invDist3;

            // --- Calculate forces for the bodies: magnitude times direction
            fx_temp += magnitude*dx;
            fy_temp += magnitude*dy;
            fz_temp += magnitude*dz;
        }
        __syncthreads();

        // --- Stores local memory to global memory
        fx_d[tid] = fx_temp;
        fy_d[tid] = fy_temp;
        fz_d[tid] = fz_temp;
    }
}

/*******************************************/
/* KERNEL FUNCTION: TILING + SHARED MEMORY */
/*******************************************/
template<int BLOCKSIZE>
__global__
void KernelcomputeForces_Tiling_Shared(float* m_d, float* x_d, float* y_d, float* z_d, float* fx_d, float* fy_d, float* fz_d, unsigned int N)
{
    float invDist, invDist3;

    for (unsigned int tid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
                  tid < N;
                  tid += blockDim.x*gridDim.x) {

        __shared__ float x_sh[BLOCKSIZE], y_sh[BLOCKSIZE], z_sh[BLOCKSIZE], m_sh[BLOCKSIZE];

        // --- Initialize register accumulators for forces
        float fx_temp = 0.0f, fy_temp = 0.0f, fz_temp = 0.0f;

        // --- Move target particle data to registers
        float x_reg = x_d[tid], y_reg = y_d[tid], z_reg = z_d[tid], m_reg = m_d[tid];

        // --- Interact all with all    
        for(unsigned int ib=0; ib<N; ib+=BLOCKSIZE) {

            // --- Loading data to shared memory
            x_sh[threadIdx.x] = x_d[ib + threadIdx.x];
            y_sh[threadIdx.x] = y_d[ib + threadIdx.x];
            z_sh[threadIdx.x] = z_d[ib + threadIdx.x];
            m_sh[threadIdx.x] = m_d[ib + threadIdx.x];

            __syncthreads();

#pragma unroll
            for(unsigned int ic=0; ic<BLOCKSIZE; ic++) {

                // --- Compute relative distances
                float dx = (x_sh[ic] - x_reg);
                float dy = (y_sh[ic] - y_reg);
                float dz = (z_sh[ic] - z_reg);
                float distanceSquared = dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz;

                // --- Prevent slingshots and division by zero
                distanceSquared += SOFTENING;

                float invDist = rsqrtf(distanceSquared);
                float invDist3 = invDist * invDist * invDist;

                // --- Calculate gravitational magnitude between the bodies
                float magnitude = GRAVITATIONAL_CONST * (m_reg * m_sh[ic]) * invDist3;

                // --- Calculate forces for the bodies: magnitude times direction
                fx_temp += magnitude*dx;
                fy_temp += magnitude*dy;
                fz_temp += magnitude*dz;
            }
            __syncthreads();
        }

        // --- Stores local memory to global memory
        fx_d[tid] = fx_temp;
        fy_d[tid] = fy_temp;
        fz_d[tid] = fz_temp;
    }
}

/************************************************/
/* KERNEL FUNCTION: TILING + SHUFFLE OPERATIONS */
/************************************************/
__global__
oid KernelcomputeForces_Tiling_Shuffle(float* m_d, float* x_d, float* y_d, float* z_d, float* fx_d, float* fy_d, float* fz_d, unsigned int N)
{
    float invDist, invDist3;

    const int laneid = threadIdx.x & 31;

    for (unsigned int tid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
                  tid < N;
                  tid += blockDim.x*gridDim.x) {

        // --- Initialize register accumulators for forces
        float fx_temp = 0.0f, fy_temp = 0.0f, fz_temp = 0.0f;

        // --- Move target particle data to registers
        float x_reg = x_d[tid], y_reg = y_d[tid], z_reg = z_d[tid], m_reg = m_d[tid];

        // --- Interact all with all    
        for(unsigned int ib=0; ib<N; ib+=32) {

            // --- Loading data to shared memory
            float x_src = x_d[ib + laneid];
            float y_src = y_d[ib + laneid];
            float z_src = z_d[ib + laneid];
            float m_src = m_d[ib + laneid];

#pragma unroll 32
            for(unsigned int ic=0; ic<32; ic++) {

                // --- Compute relative distances
                float dx = (__shfl(x_src, ic) - x_reg);
                float dy = (__shfl(y_src, ic) - y_reg);
                float dz = (__shfl(z_src, ic) - z_reg);
                float distanceSquared = dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz;

                // --- Prevent slingshots and division by zero
                distanceSquared += SOFTENING;

                float invDist = rsqrtf(distanceSquared);
                float invDist3 = invDist * invDist * invDist;

                // --- Calculate gravitational magnitude between the bodies
                float magnitude = GRAVITATIONAL_CONST * (m_reg * __shfl(m_src, ic)) * invDist3;

                // --- Calculate forces for the bodies: magnitude times direction
                fx_temp += magnitude*dx;
                fy_temp += magnitude*dy;
                fz_temp += magnitude*dz;
            }
            __syncthreads();
        }

        // --- Stores local memory to global memory
        fx_d[tid] = fx_temp;
        fy_d[tid] = fy_temp;
        fz_d[tid] = fz_temp;
    }
}

/*****************************************/
/* WRAPPER FUNCTION FOR GPU CALCULATIONS */
/*****************************************/
template<int BLOCKSIZE>
float GPUcomputeForces(float* m_d, float* x_d, float* y_d, float* z_d, float* fx_d, float* fy_d, float* fz_d, unsigned int N) {  
    float time;

    dim3 grid(iDivUp(N,BLOCKSIZE), 1, 1);       // --- Specifys how many blocks in three possible dimensions
    dim3 block(BLOCKSIZE, 1, 1);                // --- Threads per block

    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    gpuErrchk(cudaEventCreate(&start));
    gpuErrchk(cudaEventCreate(&stop));

    gpuErrchk(cudaEventRecord(start, 0));
    KernelcomputeForces_Shared<BLOCKSIZE><<<grid, block>>>(m_d, x_d, y_d, z_d, fx_d, fy_d, fz_d, N);
    //KernelcomputeForces_Tiling<BLOCKSIZE><<<grid, block>>>(m_d, x_d, y_d, z_d, fx_d, fy_d, fz_d, N);
    //KernelcomputeForces<BLOCKSIZE><<<grid, block>>>(m_d, x_d, y_d, z_d, fx_d, fy_d, fz_d, N);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    gpuErrchk(cudaEventRecord(stop, 0));
    gpuErrchk(cudaEventSynchronize(stop));
    gpuErrchk(cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop));

    return time;
}

/*****************************************/
/* WRAPPER FUNCTION FOR GPU CALCULATIONS */
/*****************************************/
template<int GRIDSIZE, int BLOCKSIZE>
float GPUcomputeForces_Tiling(float* m_d, float* x_d, float* y_d, float* z_d, float* fx_d, float* fy_d, float* fz_d, unsigned int N) {  
    float time;

    dim3 grid(GRIDSIZE, 1, 1);      // --- Specifys how many blocks in three possible dimensions
    dim3 block(BLOCKSIZE, 1, 1);    // --- Threads per block

    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    gpuErrchk(cudaEventCreate(&start));
    gpuErrchk(cudaEventCreate(&stop));

    gpuErrchk(cudaEventRecord(start, 0));
    //KernelcomputeForces_Tiling<BLOCKSIZE><<<grid, block>>>(m_d, x_d, y_d, z_d, fx_d, fy_d, fz_d, N);
    KernelcomputeForces_Tiling_Shuffle<<<grid, block>>>(m_d, x_d, y_d, z_d, fx_d, fy_d, fz_d, N);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    gpuErrchk(cudaEventRecord(stop, 0));
    gpuErrchk(cudaEventSynchronize(stop));
    gpuErrchk(cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop));

    return time;
}

/********************/
/* CPU CALCULATIONS */
/********************/
void CPUcomputeForces(float* m_h, float* x_h, float* y_h, float* z_h, float* fx_h, float* fy_h, float* fz_h, unsigned int N) {  

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<N; i++) {

        float invDist, invDist3;

        float fx_temp = 0.0f, fy_temp = 0.0f, fz_temp = 0.0f;

        // --- Interact all with all    
        for(unsigned int ib=0; ib<N; ib++) {

            // --- Compute relative distances
            float dx = (x_h[ib] - x_h[i]);
            float dy = (y_h[ib] - y_h[i]);
            float dz = (z_h[ib] - z_h[i]);
            float distanceSquared = dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz;

            // --- Prevent slingshots and division by zero
            distanceSquared += SOFTENING;

            float invDist = 1.f / sqrtf(distanceSquared);
            float invDist3 = invDist * invDist * invDist;

            // --- Calculate gravitational magnitude between the bodies
            float magnitude = GRAVITATIONAL_CONST * (m_h[i] * m_h[ib]) * invDist3;

            // --- Calculate forces for the bodies: magnitude times direction
            fx_temp += magnitude*dx;
            fy_temp += magnitude*dy;
            fz_temp += magnitude*dz;

        }

        // --- Stores local memory to global memory
        fx_h[i] = fx_temp;
        fy_h[i] = fy_temp;
        fz_h[i] = fz_temp;
    }
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main(void)
{
    const int N = 16384;

    size_t gsize = sizeof(float) * size_t(N);

    float * g[10], * _g[7];

    for(int i=0; i<7; i++) gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc((void **)&_g[i], gsize)); 

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) g[i] = (float *)malloc(gsize);

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
            *(g[j]+i) = (float)rand();

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(_g[i], g[i], gsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)); 

    // --- Warm up to take context establishment time out.
    GPUcomputeForces<512>(_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N);
    //GPUcomputeForces_Tiling<32,512>(_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N);

    // --- Bench runs
    printf("1024: %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces<512>   (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("512:  %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces<512>   (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("256:  %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces<256>   (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("128:  %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces<128>   (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("64:   %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces<64>    (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("32:   %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces<32>    (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));

    printf("16, 1024: %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces_Tiling<16,512> (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("8,  1024: %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces_Tiling<8,512>  (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("4,  1024: %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces_Tiling<4,512>  (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("32, 512: %f\n",     GPUcomputeForces_Tiling<32,512> (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("16, 512: %f\n",     GPUcomputeForces_Tiling<16,512> (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("8,  512: %f\n",     GPUcomputeForces_Tiling<8,512>  (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("64, 256:  %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces_Tiling<64,256> (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("32, 256:  %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces_Tiling<32,256> (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("16, 256:  %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces_Tiling<16,256> (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("128,128:  %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces_Tiling<128,128>(_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("64, 128:  %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces_Tiling<64,128> (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("32, 128:  %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces_Tiling<32,128> (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("256,64:   %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces_Tiling<256,64> (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
printf("128,64:   %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces_Tiling<128,64> (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("64, 64:   %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces_Tiling<64,64>  (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("512,32:   %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces_Tiling<512,32> (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("256,32:   %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces_Tiling<512,32> (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));
    printf("128,32:   %f\n",    GPUcomputeForces_Tiling<512,32> (_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6],N));

    for(int i=8; i<10; i++) gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(g[i], _g[i-3], gsize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)); 

    CPUcomputeForces(g[0],g[1],g[2],g[3],g[4],g[5],g[6],N);

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        for(int j=8; j<10; j++) {

            if (abs(*(g[j]+i) - *(g[j-3]+i)) > 0.001f) {
                printf("Error at %i, %i; GPU = %f; CPU = %f\n",i, (j-8), *(g[j-3]+i), *(g[j]+i));
                return;
            }
        }

    printf("Test passed!\n");

    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

Here are some results for `N = 16384`.

*`KernelcomputeForces`*: optimal `BLOCKSIZE = 128`; `t = 10.07ms`.

*`KernelcomputeForces_Shared`*: optimal `BLOCKSIZE = 128`; `t = 7.04ms`.

*`KernelcomputeForces_Tiling`*: optimal `BLOCKSIZE = 128`; `t = 11.14ms`.

*`KernelcomputeForces_Tiling_Shared`*: optimal `GRIDSIZE = 64`; optimal `BLOCKSIZE = 256`; `t = 7.20ms`.

*`KernelcomputeForces_Tiling_Shuffle`*: optimal `GRIDSIZE = 128`; optimal `BLOCKSIZE = 128`; `t = 6.84ms`.

Warp shuffle operations seem to *very slightly* improve the performance against shared memory.

Answer (score 5):

Before doing anything else, try running more blocks. A given block only ever runs on a single SM - by using only 16 blocks you are guaranteeing that about 40% of the GPU capacity will be idle. Some multiple of 27 should be the optimal number of blocks on your GTX260-216. You might also find that reducing the number of threads per block won't hurt performance, so that you can keep about the same amount of work per thread, but just do it with enough blocks to cover all the SM in the GPU.

**EDIT**:
Just to illustrate the point, consider this little test harness for your kernel:

```
template<int blocksize, int gridsize>
extern float GPUcomputeForces( unsigned int n, float* gm, float* gpx, float* gpy, float* gpz, float* gfx, float* gfy, float* gfz ){  
    float time;

    dim3 gridDim( gridsize, 1, 1 ); //specifys how many blocks in three possible dimensions
    dim3 blockDim( blocksize, 1, 1 ); //threads per block

    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    errchk( cudaEventCreate(&start) );
    errchk( cudaEventCreate(&stop) );

    errchk( cudaEventRecord(start, 0) );
    KernelcomputeForces<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>( n, gm, gpx, gpy, gpz, gfx, gfy, gfz );
    rterrchk;

    errchk( cudaEventRecord(stop, 0) );
    errchk( cudaEventSynchronize(stop) );
    errchk( cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop) );

    return time;
}

int main(void)
{
    const int n = 16384;
    size_t gsize = sizeof(float) * size_t(n);

    float * g[4], * _g[7];

    errchk( cudaSetDevice(1) );  // GTX 275

    for(int i=0; i<7; i++) 
        errchk( cudaMalloc((void **)&_g[i], gsize) ); 

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        g[i] = (float *)malloc(gsize);

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
    *(g[j]+i) = (float)drand48();

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) 
        errchk( cudaMemcpy(_g[i], g[i], gsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) ); 

    // Warm up to take context establishment time out.
    GPUcomputeForces<16,512>(n,_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6]);

    // Bench runs
    printf("(1,1)@(512,1,1): %f\n", GPUcomputeForces<1,512>(n,_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6]) );
    printf("(8,1)@(512,1,1): %f\n", GPUcomputeForces<8,512>(n,_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6]) );
    printf("(16,1)@(512,1,1): %f\n", GPUcomputeForces<16,512>(n,_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6]) );
    printf("(30,1)@(256,1,1): %f\n", GPUcomputeForces<30,256>(n,_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6]) );
    printf("(60,1)@(128,1,1): %f\n", GPUcomputeForces<60,128>(n,_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6]) );
    printf("(120,1)@(64,1,1): %f\n", GPUcomputeForces<120,64>(n,_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6]) );
    printf("(240,1)@(32,1,1): %f\n", GPUcomputeForces<240,32>(n,_g[0],_g[1],_g[2],_g[3],_g[4],_g[5],_g[6]) );

    cudaThreadExit();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run that, I get the following execution times on a stock GTX 275 (all times are in milliseconds):

```
(1,1)@(512,1,1): 1087.107910
(8,1)@(512,1,1): 135.582458
(16,1)@(512,1,1): 67.876671
(30,1)@(256,1,1): 54.881279
(60,1)@(128,1,1): 35.261280
(120,1)@(64,1,1): 36.316288
(240,1)@(32,1,1): 39.870495
```

Ie: Running at least as many blocks as there are MP on the card is critical to improving performance, even when using very small block sizes.

Comment: what you just asked me to do was just plain wrong. changed from 16 -> 27 reduced my fps to 16. changed from 512 -> 256 reduced my fps to 10

Comment: @ColacX - you will want to try MANY kernel configurations. Different configurations have a major impact, and usually have sweet spots.

Comment: @ColacX - I am very surprised by that. My own benchmarking of your kernel on a similar card (a GTX 275) clearly shows that the kernel execution time with at least as many blocks as your card has SM  gives almost a halving of kernel execution time. Precisely as I predicted. See my edit for more information.

Comment: `code
(16,1)@(512,1,1): 36.050186 ms
(32,1)@(256,1,1): 35.151672 ms
(48,1)@(256,1,1): 34.227173 ms
(64,1)@(128,1,1): 31.856787 ms
(27,1)@(512,1,1): 40.098667 ms
(54,1)@(64,1,1): 60.681877 ms
(54,1)@(128,1,1): 40.320881 ms
(54,1)@(256,1,1): 36.719494 ms
(54,1)@(512,1,1): 39.685223 ms
(81,1)@(64,1,1): 50.386776 ms
(81,1)@(128,1,1): 31.069546 ms
(81,1)@(256,1,1): 36.522266 ms
(81,1)@(512,1,1): 39.731533 ms
(108,1)@(64,1,1): 40.844597 ms
(108,1)@(128,1,1): 35.667061 ms
(108,1)@(256,1,1): 35.841301 ms
(108,1)@(512,1,1): 39.554295 ms
`
multiples of 27 does not seem to improve that much

Comment: Are you really sure you are running this code an a GTX 260-216? Those bench numbers look totally different to the GTX 275 I used. Also the GTX 260 should be about 15-20% slower than the 275 (lower shader and memory clock) yet your results show about 50% higher performance at the smallest block size. I have a **lot** of experience tuning code for these cards - something here doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: The results don't make sense and it is my fault. I will update the post to reflect this when I get some time.

Comment: yep i bought a gtx 260 i still have a the box and receit and it says so in device manager and when i print out the device properties
well im sure of my benchmark but your test above there seem to mostly test multiples of 30. maybee you could try multiples of 32 aswell

my for loops in the kernel code increments by the number of threads for each iteration maybe that has some importance, i got that from an example perhaps theres a different way to iterate

Comment: thanks man you are very diligent in helping me i appreciate it

Comment: The multiples of 30 is because the GTX275 has 30SM, where as your GTX 275 has either 24 or 27, depending on which model you have. Otherwise the two are very similar GPUs, the memory system is the same, just that the GTX275 is clocked a bit higher.

Answer (score 4):

I want to provide a separate, additional answer to the one provided above which, I think, will be useful to next users.

A way to further optimize the N-body problem is to resort to tree-based approaches, like the Barnes-Hut one, which was parallelized in

```
M. Burtscher, K. Pingali, "An Efficient CUDA Implementation of the Tree-Based Barnes Hut n-Body
```

Algorithm", GPU Computing Gems, Emerald Edition.

and whose CUDA implementation is downloadable at [LonestarGPU](http://iss.ices.utexas.edu/?p=projects/galois/lonestargpu).

Comparing the above shared- and shuffle-based kernels with the mentioned implementation on a Kepler K20c, I have obtained the following results (times in ms)

```
N           Barnes-Hut          Shared          Shuffle
16384       19.1                5.7             7.2
32768       46.9                25.5            21.7
65536       107.7               102.6           74.6
131072      255.1               355             296.2
262144      548.3               1408.8          1108.9
524288      1246                5434            4688
1048576     2674                21544           18632
2097152     5664                85980           74454
```

Please, note that such an analysis is not available in the original publication quoted above.

Answer (score 3):

The cuda profiler will tell you information about occupancy, conditional branching, global memory usage (cache misses or uncoalesced reads, depending on cuda version), and more. It is an essential part of optimizing your kernel.

Comment: oh didnt know there was one ill check it out
although i bet theres nothing obvious i can see in the profiler. could still use some tips on changing the code