# CUDA n body shared memory does not speed up the computation

Tags: cuda

I am quite new in CUDA. I wrote a short code ONLY for testing the kernel for computing accelerations of mass particles. I test it using only *time ./example*. I have Kubuntu 12.04, Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU 760 @ 2.80GHz, GeForce GTX 560, and compile it by using nvcc -O3 -arch=sm_20 -o example example.cu. Here is my code.

```
 #include <math.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

  __global__ void acc_sh(double *x, double *y, double *z, double *ax, double *ay, double *az, double *mass, int N)
{

  extern __shared__ double4 shPos[]; //make dynamic

  int p = blockDim.x;
  int idx = blockIdx.x*p + threadIdx.x;

  if (idx > N-1) return;

    double3 acc = (double3){0.0,0.0,0.0};

   double posx = x[idx];
   double posy = y[idx];
   double posz = z[idx];

   // Tile
   for (int k = 0; k < N; k += p) {

   //Load positions into shmem
   shPos[threadIdx.x].x = x[k + threadIdx.x];
   shPos[threadIdx.x].y = y[k + threadIdx.x];
   shPos[threadIdx.x].z = z[k + threadIdx.x];
   shPos[threadIdx.x].w = mass[k + threadIdx.x];

   __syncthreads();

    for (int j = 0; j < p && k + j < N; j++) {

     //Loop over the shmem
     double rijx = posx - shPos[j].x;
     double rijy = posy - shPos[j].y;
     double rijz = posz - shPos[j].z;

     double dist = rijx*rijx + rijy*rijy + rijz*rijz;
     double dist3 = dist*dist*dist;
     double apre = 0.0;

     if (dist3 != 0) //avoid self-interaction
      {
       apre = rsqrt(dist3)*shPos[j].w;
      }

     acc.x += apre*rijx;
     acc.y += apre*rijy;
     acc.z += apre*rijz;

    }

   __syncthreads();

  }

  ax[idx] = acc.x;
  ay[idx] = acc.y;
  az[idx] = acc.z;

 }

__global__ void acc(double *x, double *y, double *z, double *ax, double *ay, double *az, double *mass, int N)
 {

  int p = blockDim.x;
  int idx = blockIdx.x*p + threadIdx.x;

  if (idx > N-1) return;

  double3 acc = (double3){0.0,0.0,0.0};

  double posx = x[idx];
  double posy = y[idx];
  double posz = z[idx];

  // Do not use shmem and loop over all bodies
   for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {

     double rijx = posx - x[k];
     double rijy = posy - y[k];
     double rijz = posz - y[k];

     double dist = rijx*rijx + rijy*rijy + rijz*rijz;
     double dist3 = dist*dist*dist;
     double apre = 0.0;

     if (dist3 != 0) //avoid self-interaction
      {
       apre = rsqrt(dist3)*mass[k];
      }

     acc.x += apre*rijx;
     acc.y += apre*rijy;
     acc.z += apre*rijz;

     __syncthreads();

   }

   ax[idx] = acc.x;
   ay[idx] = acc.y;
   az[idx] = acc.z;

  }

int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));

  const int N = 16384;
  double t, dt, tend;

  //INIT TEST PARTICLES
  // HOST
  double *x, *y, *z, *mass;
  double *ax, *ay, *az, *dmass;

 //DEVICE
 double *dx, *dy, *dz;
 double *dax, *day, *daz;

 double size = N*sizeof(double);

 cudaMalloc((void**)&dx, size);
 cudaMalloc((void**)&dy, size);
 cudaMalloc((void**)&dz, size);
 cudaMalloc((void**)&dmass, size);

 cudaMalloc((void**)&dax, size);
 cudaMalloc((void**)&day, size);
 cudaMalloc((void**)&daz, size);

 x = (double*) malloc(size);
 y = (double*) malloc(size);
 z = (double*) malloc(size);
 mass = (double*) malloc(size);

 ax = (double*) malloc(size);
 ay = (double*) malloc(size);
 az = (double*) malloc(size);

 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {

   x[i] = (double) rand()/RAND_MAX;
   y[i] = (double) rand()/RAND_MAX;
   z[i] = (double) rand()/RAND_MAX;
   mass[i] = (double) rand()/RAND_MAX;

   // printf("%d %10.5e %10.5e %10.5e %10.5e \n", i, x[i], y[i], z[i], mass[i]);
   ax[i] = 0;
   ay[i] = 0;
   az[i] = 0;

  }

 cudaMemcpy(dx, x, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
 cudaMemcpy(dy, y, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
 cudaMemcpy(dz, z, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
 cudaMemcpy(dmass, mass, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

 cudaMemcpy(dax, ax, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
 cudaMemcpy(day, ay, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
 cudaMemcpy(daz, az, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

 t = 0.0; //start integ. time
 tend = 365.0; //end integr. time, about one year
 dt = 1.0;

 int TPB = 128;
 int BPG = (N/TPB)+1;

//********************************************************
//********************************************************
//********************************************************
//MAIN CYCLE**********************************************
//********************************************************
//********************************************************
//********************************************************


  while (t <= tend) {

     printf("time [d] %24.20f \n", t);
     acc_sh<<< BPG, TPB, sizeof(double4)*TPB >>>(dx,dy,dz,dax,day,daz,dmass,N);
     //acc<<< BPG, TPB >>>(dx,dy,dz,dax,day,daz,dmass,N);
     t += dt;
  }

  cudaMemcpy(x, dx, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaMemcpy(y, dy, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaMemcpy(z, dz, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  cudaMemcpy(ax, dax, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaMemcpy(ay, day, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaMemcpy(az, daz, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

//********************************************************
//********************************************************
//********************************************************
//OUTPUT RESULTS******************************************
//********************************************************
//********************************************************
//********************************************************

/*for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
  printf("%d %23.16e %23.16e %23.16e \n", j+1, ax[j], ay[j], az[j]);
  }*/

 cudaFree(dx);
 cudaFree(dy);
 cudaFree(dz);

 cudaFree(ax);
 cudaFree(ay);
 cudaFree(az);

 return 0;

}
```

When I run it and measure the total time of app running, I obtain these running times:

NO SHARED (in MAIN CYCLE only *acc_sh* is commented):
real    0m44.933s
user    0m32.838s
sys     0m12.001s

SHARED (in MAIN CYCLE only *acc* is commented):
real    0m44.259s
user    0m32.710s
sys     0m11.445s

Times are comparable! Why? I expected, that when I use acc_sh which uses shared memory, it should be faster... Next question is: why is the program at the beginning so fast, and at the *tend* it waits for "something"?

Comment: Edit your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25121233/n-body-in-cuda-with-and-without-using-shared-memory-performance-is-the-same) (yes, you can edit your own question.  Click the edit link under the question).  Don't create a new user just to ask the same question over again.

Answer (score 2):

1. don't use a `double` quantity to specify the number of bytes to allocate or transfer:

   ```
   double size = N*sizeof(double);
   ```

   use `int`, `unsigned`, or `size_t` instead.  When I compile your code, I see numerous warnings due to this.
2. You have a bug in your `acc` kernel code which will produce incorrect results *and* affect the timing:

   ```
   double rijy = posy - y[k];
   double rijz = posz - y[k];
                        ^
                        that should be z[k], not y[k]
   ```

   This coding error significantly reduces the amount of data that your non-shared kernel needs to load, which makes this kernel (incorrectly) perform better.  If you had bothered to compare and check the results between the two cases, you would have found a discrepancy there as well.

When I fix those errors, on my particular setup, I get timings of ~21 seconds for the non-shared case, and ~18 seconds for the shared case.

If you're looking for 10x improvement going from global to shared memory, that's simply implausible.  Shared memory bandwidth is only about 5x better than global memory bandwidth, so it's unreasonable to expect 10x even in a perfect case.  Furthermore, this type of comparison discounts the effect of the L1 and L2 caches in your GPU, which can bring global memory accesses, for frequently accessed data, up to nearly the level of shared memory.

Regarding this question: "why is the program at the beginning so fast, and at the tend it waits for "something"?" The kernel launches are *asynchronous*.  The kernel launch returns control to the host thread before the kernel begins executing.   When you launch a kernel in a loop like this, it launches, and then immediately returns control to the host thread (before that kernel begins executing), which launches the next kernel.

Comment: I repared the bug and my timings are: Shared: real 0m44.248s user 0m32.854s sys 0m11.309s, NoShared: real 0m45.448s user 0m33.498s sys 0m11.853s. So about 2.5 % speed up... Isn't it too small?

Comment: And what GPU, CPU and OS do you have?

Comment: `Isn't it too small?` Why?  Did you read what I said about caches?  Config: Quadro5000, Xeon W570 3.2GHz, RHEL 5.5

Comment: Because you have speedup about 15%, I have 2.5%. And generally, your computation takes 18s, my 44s... So I am asking why only 2.5%...

Comment: Our GPUs are different too.  I have a cc2.0 GPU with 11 SMs, and you have a cc2.1 GPU with 7 SMs.  This may have an impact relative to the size of the cache, on the benefit of the cache.  Since my GPU can have more threadblocks and warps in flight, it may have a larger working set footprint, meaning more stress on the cache.  You GPU may have a smaller working set that fits better with the cache.

Comment: @user3907668 Robert is right in his point that shared memory improves the performance. I have tested his [full code](http://pastebin.com/uGh9UhbT) on an 1) old architecture (GT210, cc. 1.2) and 2) on a new one (Kepler K20c, cc. 3.5) and these are the timings: 1) `253ms` vs. `422ms` (speedup = `1.6`); 2) `23ms` vs. `46ms` (speedup = `2`). See also @talonmies answer to [Help me optimize my N-Body CUDA application kernel code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611905/help-me-optimize-my-n-body-cuda-application-kernel-code).

Comment: Perfect :) Here is the rule like "do not say thanks, etc." BUT THANK YOU ROBERT A LOT :)